# How to download pkg files from iTunes?

Tags: iphone, itunes, install, pkg

I need to download a pkg(ipa) file from the Apple Store (using iTunes, i guess iPhone apps are only in iTunes not in the Store App).

How can you download the pkg file(ipa)? (Alternatively, if I downloaded it with iTunes, it says downloaded, where can I find it on the hard drive?)

I was running find / on the entire filesystem but still cant find it.

Comment: iOS apps are distributed as .ipa files which is a different format than .pkg. It might be easier for people to help you though if you could add some details about what you want to do with the file afterwards/which problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks patrix. I can't find ipa files either on my drive.

Comment: @istvan - take a stepor two back and explain what you want to do - downloading the .ipa might not be the waty to do it (I can't think of a reason to do that)

Comment: I would like to install an application in the simulator to be able to see what is happening. I am not the developer of that app but I need to get something fixed. I would like to install it and tcpdump the network communication it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Downloaded iOS applications are stored in your iTunes library. To find the physical location on disk

- go to the Apps section in iTunes, right-click on the app and select "Reveal in Finder"
- use the Goto command in Finder to open `~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Mobile\ Applications/`